# Extract numbers using grep command

Tags: grep

I have the following file example:

```
some text is here  
   sometext(1,21);
   sometext(2,9);
   sometext(3,231);
   sometext(10,1112);
   sometext(11,17)
Some text is here
```

I'm trying to extract the second number in the parentheses of the lines containing `sometext`, so in the above example, the numbers `21`,`9`,`231`,`1112`,`17`.

I didn't find a suitable `grep` command for the above pattern.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using GNU `grep` you can use an RE that will match digits after a comma

```
grep -oP ',\K\d+' file
```

The native `perl` equivalent is this

```
perl -lne 'print for /,\K\d+/g' file
```

Comment: `perl -lne 'print for /,\K\d+/g'` or `perl -lne 'print $1 while /,(\d+)/g'` (or `pcregrep -o1 ',(\d+)'`) to handle more than one `sometext(x,y)` per line like the `grep` approach with perl regexps does would be better.

Comment: You can also use `sed  -n 's/.*,\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/p'` to avoid perl regular experssions.

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` utility is unsuitable for extracting part of a line, at least if you want to use standard Unix tooling. The standard `grep` utility filters complete lines matching a pattern, but there is no natural way of pulling out parts of the lines.  To manipulate lines in a more detailed manner, one may use, e.g., `sed`.

Assuming that the text is much longer and more varied than what you show, we may let the text string `sometext(` tell us when to process a line for that second integer value.  Once we see that string in the data, we may trim off the flanking bits before and after the second integer.

Here we apply two trimming substitutions, one from the start of the line up to including the last comma on the line, and one from the right parenthesis to the end of the line. We turn off the default printing of each line with `-n` and explicitly print the resulting string after the second substitution.

```bsh
sed -n '/sometext(/ { s/.*,//; s/).*//p; }' file
```

We may also choose to delete any line that does not match our special trigger string and apply the two substitutions to any line that remains.

```bsh
sed -e '/sometext(/!d' -e 's/.*,//' -e 's/).*//' file
```

If you want the resulting list of numbers as a comma-delimited list (like what you showed in the question), then consider piping the result of the above command through

```bsh
paste -d, -s -
```

Given the data in your question, we get:

```
$ sed -e '/sometext(/!d' -e 's/.*,//' -e 's/).*//' file | paste -d, -s -
21,9,231,1112,17
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `awk` for this, with field separators of comma or close-parenthesis (`-F'[,)]'`).
This makes the numbers you want in field 2 (`$2`).  Combine that with a check that $2 contains only digits:

```
$ awk -F'[,)]' '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {print $2}' input.txt 
21
9
231
1112
17
```

This assumes $2 contains only non-negative integers. If it might contain negative and/or real numbers, use the following instead:

```
awk -F'[,)]' '$2 ~ /^[-+]?[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$/ {print $2}' input.txt
```

NOTE: because awk is using a comma as a field separator, this won't work in locales that use comma as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to do the heavy lifting and then clean up with `tr` — assuming you don’t want the commas. It’s also not clear from the post how you would like the output to be presented, this produces a list of newline separated digits.

```
grep -Eo ",[[:digit:]]+" input.txt | tr -d ","
```

Or, avoiding use of `tr` for a `grep` only solution:

```
grep -Eo ",[[:digit:]]+" input.txt | grep -Eo "[^,]+"
```